# Promoting my site on Facebook with my primary account, or create a new account?

Tags: social-media, website-promotion

I am about to launch my website and I so far have been using my personal account to promote the site in relevant groups etc.  If I start to promote the site in a larger geographical area should I be concerned with using my personal account? Should I create a fake account just for this promotion so it's not tied to my personal account?

I have created a Facebook Page, but I can't use it to post in relevant FB groups which is where the interested people would be.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Good Facebook marketing strategies should comply with the terms of use of Facebook. Marketing on Facebook is good but takes time to establish a user base from likes, shares, fans. A potential account that is at risk of closure is not a very good campaign. Facebook has and continues to close accounts based on false information and duplicate identity's.

> [*Registration and Account Security*](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms)
>
> Facebook users provide their real names and information, and we need
>   your help to keep it that way. Here are some commitments you make to
>   us relating to registering and maintaining the security of your
>   account:
>
> - You will not provide any false personal information on Facebook, or
>     create an account for anyone other than yourself without permission.
> - You will not create more than one personal account.

Comment: Good points, any suggestions on how to then promote my site inside a Facebook Group?

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a "page" on Facebook for your site (through your existing Facebook account), you can choose how posts on the page will appear (either as yourself, or as from the page itself).  There is no reason to create another account because Facebook allows you to adopt the persona of your page through your existing account.  You can also make other people administrators of this page which will allow them to post to it in the same manner.

Comment: I understand that but the problem arises when I need to go out and advertise to the relevant groups for my site. I can't post at "Site XYZ" I have to post as "Mark".

Comment: From your page you can choose "Share page" and then "In a group" to share the page with that group as the persona of your page.

Comment: I only have "Invite Contacts by Email" this is an option under the page area?

Comment: When I go to my page, I have an "Insights" section. The "Share page" is last in that section right below "Invite email contacts"

Comment: Ah, I haven't received enough likes yet to enable the "Insights" page yet.